# Python 3 threadings.Thread callback error when targeting abstract method

Tags: multithreading, websocket, callback, abstract-class, python-3.6

base_class.py

```
import threading
import websocket
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class A:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        self.some_var = 0    

    @abstractmethod
    def failed_method(self):
        pass

    def on_websocket_message(self, ws, msg):
        var = self.failed_method()
        print(var)
    ...

    def open_websocket(self):
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp('http://some_url.com',
                                on_message=self.on_websocket_message, ...)
        ws.run_forever()

    def callback_method(self):
        websocket_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.open_websocket, name='some_websocket_name')
        another_var = self.failed_method()
        print('Another variable\'s value is [{}]'.format(another_var))
```

child_class.py

```
from base_class import A

class B(A):
    def failed_method(self):
        return 3
```

other_class.py

```
import threading
from child_class import B

def main():
    child_class_instance = B()
    some_thread = threadings.Thread(target=child_class_instance.callback_method, name='some_name')
    some_thread.start()
```

The result of `main()` is printed `None`, not `3`, i.e., abstract class' method is called instead of child's one. (Assume all the modules are in the one place.)

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Or what is the thing I do not understand in inheritance in Python combined with `threadings.Thread`?

P.S. With the similar code I've met `error from callback <bound method BaseClass... of < ...ChildClass...> >` from `websocket.WebSocketApp._callback()`.

P.P.S. Important to note that I use `websocket-client`, not `websockets`.

Comment: In a 2.7 shell I get the value 3, as you were expecting. Inheritance is not affected by threading AFAIK

Comment: @John, sorry to mislead you: the problem might be in websockets as well. Updated the code.